# Sufficient conditions for $ \frac{\sum_{k=1}^N {p_k}G(x+e_k)}{G(x)} $ increases/decreases where $\sum_{k=1}^N p_k e_k = 0 $ and $\sum_{k=1}^N p_k = 1$

Tags: calculus, probability, convex-analysis

Suppose that $0 \leq G(x) \leq 1$, $G'(x)<0$, $ G $ is smooth enough and $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I want to find some neat sufficient conditions for $ H(x) = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^N {p_k}G(x+e_k)}{G(x)} $ is increasing (decreasing) in $x$, where $\sum_{k=1}^N p_k e_k = 0$ and $\sum_{k=1}^N p_k = 1$, $\forall N \in \mathbb N $, for all posible combinations of $p_k >0$ and $e_k$.

An obvious sufficient condition for $H(x)$ to be increasing is $G'''(x)>0$. However, the symmetric version ($G'''(x)<0$) does not guarantee a decreasing $H(x)$ .

(1) Are there any sufficient conditions that are "symmetric" for increasing $H(x)$ and decreasing $H(x)$?

(2) Are there tighter sufficient conditions, or sufficient and necessary conditions?

Answer (score 1):

The condition $G'''(x) < 0$ is actually not enough to guarantee $H(x)$ is increasing. Let
\begin{align*}
G(x) = \left\{1 -\frac{9}{5}x + \frac{3}{5}x^2 + \frac{1}{5}x^3\right\}\mathbb{I}(0 \le x \le 1)
\end{align*}
We can confirm $G(x) \in [0, 1]$, $G'(x) \le 0$ on $[0, 1]$, and $G'''(x) = 6/5 > 0$. Then, take, say, $p_1 = p_2 = 1/2$ and $e_1 = 0, e_2 = \epsilon$. Then
\begin{align*}
H(x) = \frac{0.5(1 -\frac{9}{5}x + \frac{3}{5}x^2 + \frac{1}{5}x^3) + 0.5(1 -\frac{9}{5}(x+\epsilon) + \frac{3}{5}(x+\epsilon)^2 + \frac{1}{5}(x+\epsilon)^3)}{1 -\frac{9}{5}x + \frac{3}{5}x^2 + \frac{1}{5}x^3}
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}H(x)\bigg|_{x = \epsilon/2} = \frac{\epsilon(-54\epsilon^3 - 396\epsilon^2 - 936\epsilon + 816)}{(\epsilon-2)^2(\epsilon+10)^2}
\end{align*}
If I plug in, for example, $\epsilon = 0.1$, then the quantity above is $\approx -0.103$, and therefore $H(x)$ is decreasing. I know my $G$ is restricted to $[0, 1]$, but you can imagine a smoother on $G$ so that it is on the entire real line.

**Sufficient conditions**

If we suppose $\mathcal{E}$ follows a discrete distribution with on $(e_1, \cdots, e_N)$ with respective probabilities $(p_1, \cdots, p_N)$, then we may write
\begin{align*}
H(x) = \frac{\mathbb{E}[G(x+\mathcal{E})]}{G(x)}
\end{align*}
where the expectation is taken with respect to the above defined distribution. The derivative of the log is
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx} \log H(x) = \frac{\mathbb{E}[G'(x+\mathcal{E})]}{\mathbb{E}[G(x+\mathcal{E})]} - \frac{G'(x)}{G(x)}
\end{align*}
where I was able to bring the derivative into $\mathbb{E}$ by assuming "$G$ is smooth enough". If $H(x)$ were to be increasing, then $\frac{d}{dx} \log H(x) \ge 0$, or
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathbb{E}[G'(x+\mathcal{E})]}{\mathbb{E}[G(x+\mathcal{E})]} \ge \frac{G'(x)}{G(x)} 
\end{align*}
Therefore, sufficient conditions are
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[G'(x+\mathcal{E})] \ge G'(x) \qquad \text{and} \qquad \mathbb{E}[G(x+\mathcal{E})] \le G(x)
\end{align*}
and sufficient conditions for this are
\begin{align*}
G' \text{ is convex and } G \text{ is concave}
\end{align*}
and sufficient conditions for this are
\begin{align*}
G''' > 0, G'' < 0
\end{align*}
If you rework this proof above, you'll also see sufficient conditions for $H(x)$ to be decreasing is $G''' < 0, G'' > 0$.

Comment: Thank you! The sufficient condition is brilliant, except you that ignored that $G'(x)<0$. Hence the second sufficient condition should be $\qquad \mathbb{E}[G(x+\mathcal{E})] \ge G(x)$
\end{align*}. Hence the sufficient condition should be $ G'''>0,  G''>0$.    Your counterexample doesn't work because you need to have $p_1e_!+p_2e_2=0$

Comment: Ahh, I did miss $\mathbb{E}(\mathcal{E}) = 0$. It seems that the ratio condition $\mathbb{E}[G'(x+\mathcal{E})]/\mathbb{E}[G(x+\mathcal{E})] \ge G'(x)/G(x)$ would not be satisfied unless $\mathbb{E}[G(x+\mathcal{E})]$ were sufficiently small.